# Should I use `DateTimeInterface` in my php project?

Tags: php, datetime, interface

Recently, I discovered that there is a [`DateTimeInterface`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php). As I was working with `\DateTime` and `\DateTimeImmutable`, I thought that it'd be good to typehint for.

Yet on the Changelog on php.net it says that since 5.5.8:

> Trying to implement DateTimeInterface raises a fatal error now. Formerly implementing the interface didn't raise an error, but the
>   behavior was erroneous.

This reads that I never be able to implement my own `CustomDateTime` class implementing the `DateTimeInterface`, which seems rather odd.

Should I use the `DateTimeInterface` in my userland code?

My gut feeling tells me not to. Yet it also doesn't feel right to typehint the object, i.e.

```
@var \DateTime|\DateTimeImmutable|\MyCustomDateTime
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `DateTimeInterface` typehint when you expect either one of the native DateTime variants, e.g. `\DateTime` or `\DateTimeImmutable`.

But as the docs say

> It is not possible to implement this interface with userland classes.

So if you plan to implement `\DateTimeInterface` with your own implementation, this will not work, e.g.

```
class MyDateTime implements \DateTimeInterface {} // will raise an error
```

However, you can create your own interface and adapt the native DateTime classes.

```
interface MyDateTime { /* some methods */ }

class NativeDateTime implements MyDateTime 
{
    private $dateTime;

    public function __construct($args = 'now') {
        $this->dateTime = new \DateTimeImmutable($args);
    }

   /* some methods */
}
```

Or you can extend the native DateTime variants, which will then implement the `DateTimeInterface` obviously, e.g.

```
class MyDateTime extends \DateTimeImmutable 
{
    /* your modifications */
}

var_dump(new MyDateTime instanceof \DateTimeInterface); // true
```

Details why you cannot implement your own classes implementing `\DateTimeInterface`:

- https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/512
- https://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg79534.html

> tl;dr core functions that accept `DateTime` and `DateTimeImmutable` (`DateTimeInterface` basically) operate directly on timelib structures hence they will break if you pass them a user-defined class. There's a workaround though - it's to always call user-defined class's method directly from built-in functions, so if you would call `(new DateTime())->diff(new UserDefinedDateTime())` it would call `UserDefinedDateTime#diff` in the end which would need to implement the logic.

Answer (score 4):

I would say you should not.

> The \DateTimeInterface is an implementation detail of ext/date that should not have been exposed to userland code.

See the RFC created for removing it: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/drop-datetimeinterface

Comment: Status of that "Request For Comments" is "Draft". Far bigger problem is the existence of DateTime (and not keeping just DateTimeImmutable). I suggest that if you can, use `\DateTimeImmutable` https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php

Answer (score 0):

You are encouraged to type hint against DateTimeInterface when you accept

1. DateTime
2. DateTimeImmutable
3. Any class derived from these

You can however not implement DateTimeInterface without extending from either DateTime or DateTimeImmutable due to internal details.

You can ignore https://wiki.php.net/rfc/drop-datetimeinterface as by now - years after the question - we know that the community decided against removing the interface.